# How to streamline multiple fetchrequests

Tags: optimization, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I’m working on a simple stats page for my app, that basically counts up instances of a particular set of strings. I’ve got a working version using multiple fetch requests, but I have to imagine there’s a better/cheaper way of doing it.

```
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]) var entries: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "red")) var redCount: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "orange")) var orangeCount: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "yellow")) var yellowCount: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "green")) var greenCount: FetchedResults<Entry>
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", "blue")) var blueCount: FetchedResults<Entry>
```

Each of the color variables are used like so:

```
numberCell(label: "Red", value: redCount.count)
```

The first fetch request is there because I’m showing the date of the first entry on the stats page too.

I’m very new to swiftui but I’m interested in learning how to optimize things.

Comment: Save yourself a lot of work and use sectioned fetch request

Comment: Have a look at this. Short video that answers a lot of questions. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui